# Problem with cellForRowAtIndexPath and NSBundle mainBundle

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsbundle, custom-cell

have an idea to solve this problem?

This is the **correct and wrong way** respectly:
[image] [image]

This is working code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)[...] cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    @try {
        newsRow = ((NewsRowController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]);
        if (newsRow == nil) {
            if ( [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"] || 
                 [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
            else [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow" owner:self options:nil];

            if ([tableArray count] > 0)
                [newsRow setData:[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }       
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"a!!!!!");
    }
    return newsRow;
}
```

...but because in my 3g device it's **slowly** *when i scroll table up/down* i changed the code in this way, inserting Device check in viewDidLoad and pass it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSArray *cRow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *cRow;
[...]
@syntetize cRow;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[...]
    if ( [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"] 
        || 
        [[Device GetModel] isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
        cRow  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow_ipad" owner:self options:nil] retain];
        else cRow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow" owner:self options:nil] retain];
[...]
}

- (UITableViewCell *)[...] cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    @try {
        newsRow = ((NewsRowController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]);
        if (newsRow == nil) {

            //
            // ADDED CODE.
            //
            newsRow = [cRow objectAtIndex:0];    
            //

            if ([tableArray count] > 0)
                [newsRow setData:[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }       
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"a!!!!!");
    }
    return newsRow;
}
```

Now the table show me only a row. If i scroll, the row change, but it show only one row...
[image]
What's the problem?

Any helps?

thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case when you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: you will get nil back because there are no cells that can be dequeued. You need to load the nib each time you get a nil cell back otherwise you won't be adding any cells to the table after the first one.

If calling GetModel is what is slowing you could call that in viewDidLoad and store it for usage later on.

More than likely your table is not scrolling smoothly because of the amount of views you are drawing in each cell. If your background will always be a solid color you should make sure that all the views you are adding to the cell or opaque. If you need an image or a gradient background then you should look at drawing the cell all in one view. Apple has a good example of how to do this here: [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318). Specifically checkout the TimeZoneView file.

Comment: You can start moving the code that loads the nib back into tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you can store a BOOL of if you are on the iPad are not using viewDidLoad. If the scrolling is still slow after that instead of a cell created in a nib create your own subclass of UITableViewCell like Apple does in the example.

Comment: perfect. And is there a way to set [[NSBundle mainBundle] loa...] in a var to use in loop?

Comment: It will still need to be called each time, so outside of just putting it inside of another method to clean up the code, there isn't really anything you can do to avoid calling it.